OpenAPI with IAsyncEnumerable RESTFul service
Can someone please provide instructions, or better still an example, of how OpenAPI would firstly document and secondly generate Javascript and C# client code for the following RESTful service: -
    [HttpGet]
    public async IAsyncEnumerable<dynamic> yieldLastName(string inName, [EnumeratorCancellation]CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inName))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Illeagal Parameter. inName is mandatory.");
            yield break;
        }

        // alter database [AdventureWorks2022] set ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION on;
        TransactionOptions txnOpts = new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Snapshot };

        List<dynamic> namesSelect = new List<dynamic>();

        SqlParameter searchName = new SqlParameter("LastName", System.Data.SqlDbType.Char);
        searchName.Value = inName + "%";

        var sql = @"
            select 
                  LastName,
                  count(*) as hitRate
            from 
                  Person.Person P
            where
                  LastName like @LastName
            group by
                  LastName
            ";

        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, txnOpts, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
        {
            using (SqlConnection cxn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cxn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(searchName);
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 120000;
                SqlDataReader reader = null!;
                Boolean hasRows = false;

                try
                {
                    await cxn.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);
                    reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(cancellationToken);
                    hasRows = await reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken);
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException ex) when (ex.CancellationToken == cancellationToken) { }

                while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && hasRows)
                {
                    string lastName = "";
                    int hitRate = 0;

                    if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
                    {
                        lastName = reader.GetString(0);
                    }
                    hitRate = reader.GetInt32(1);

                    yield return new
                    {
                        LastName = Uri.EscapeDataString(lastName),
                        HitRate = hitRate
                    };

                    try
                    {
                        hasRows = await reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken);
                    }
                    catch (TaskCanceledException ex) when (ex.CancellationToken == cancellationToken) { }

//                   await Task.Delay(100);  // Slow down the Demo
                }
            }
            scope.Complete();
        }
    } 

A complete working example can be found here You need to download a copy of the AdventureWorks database and need VisualStudio to run it.

Is there a reason why you've chosen to return a dynamic type? Like @Oliver mentioned, this is an important detail since you cannot perform type reflection on a dynamic type. Please update your question to include explain this, and also explain what you tried and what you were expecting. For more information on asking a good question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

The concrete return type varies by call and/or element returned. The only thing a tool like OpenAPI can infer at startup from this method signature is that you're returning an enumerable collection of "something." This code sample works because the dynamic instances are marshaled into a string, sent over the wire, and then unmarshaled by the JSON deserializer.

@https://stackoverflow.com/users/49720/jason-weber just to clarify the parallelism that IAsyncEnurmerable affords. the entire collection does not have to be marshalled and sent over the wire. Depending on buffer sizes and elapsed time, chunks of the collection are sent when and as available.
